# Accessing and update one data.table column using vectors

Tags: r, data.table

Consider these two dt and a vector that contains the name of some of the columns

```
mtcars=data.table(mtcars)
mydt=mtcars
mydt$disp=10
i=1
names(mtcars)
```

> ```
>      [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
>     [11] "carb"
> ```

```
myVector <- c('disp', 'hp', 'wt')
```

I often have to work on data.table with thousands of columns and have to perform different calculation on a subset of columns or one column, but I am still confused by the use of .. and with=FALSE.

For example it seems that .. cannot be used when indexing a vector, such as

```
mtcars[,..myVector[i]]
[1] "disp"
```

But only this works

```
mtcars[,myVector[i],with=FALSE]
```

Now if I want to update values in mtcars with values stored in mydt I can't find a way of accessing the values in that column. Usually the [[]] in lists return vectors
These don't work

```
mtcars[,myVector[i],with=FALSE]=mydt[,myVector[i],with=FALSE]
mtcars[,myVector[i],with=FALSE := mydt[,myVector[i],with=FALSE]]
mydt[[,myVector[i],with=TRUE]]
```

What is the correct syntax if I want to copy these values from one data.table to another? And what is the syntax to just copy the values instead of the data.table, basically the same I would get by using `mydt$disp`?

EDIT: it seems that this syntax works but I still don't understand why the .. or with=FALSE are not needed on the left hand side.

```
mtcars[,myVector[i]]=mydt[,myVector[i],with=FALSE]
mtcars[,myVector]=mydt[,myVector,with=FALSE]
```

Comment: You want to just replace the value for the entire variable, not a join? If so, I would just do just `mtcars[, (myVector[i]) := mydt[[myVector[i]]]]` I guess. Not sure what is the extend usage of `with = FALSE` for. Can't recall when I used it last time. For multiple columns `set` with a `for` loop should work.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, no it's not a join.

Comment: I don't know details but your workflow is probably suboptimal.

Comment: @Roland Yes probably it's not optimized but I am only updating a few dozen values on each column. I just find something confusing that you can get the same result with different syntax. So the with = FALSE is obsolete or not advised?

Comment: `with = FALSE` makes a copy of the whole data.table so no advised. `..` is the same as `with = FALSE` just prettier - so not advised neither (it also can't evaluate expressions, this is why `..myVector[i]` didn't work). Use `:=` and `[[` like I showed in my first comment. `get`/`mget` is also an over kill and can cause memory issues.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks, I didn't know about that use of [[ in this syntax, will try that.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I just want to point out that .. and with = FALSE are not exactly the same, see for example the different behavior I show in my question. You need to use with = FALSE when you want to select some columns that are not just in a vector, such as using c("col1",myvector) or the example I have given.

Comment: It because `..` can't evaluate expressions, I already told you that. They are the same in a sense that, when it possible `..` defaults to `with = FALSE`, when not, it just doesn't work. If you don't believe me, [check the code yourself](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R#L215-L234)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple option:

```
library(data.table)
mtcars=data.table(mtcars)
mydt=copy(mtcars) #copy is important here
mydt[, disp := 10]

i=1
myVector <- c('disp', 'hp', 'wt')

mtcars[, (myVector[i]) := mydt[, get(myVector[i])]]
 #    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 #1: 21.0   6   10 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
 #2: 21.0   6   10 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Using `(...)` on the LHS of `:=` ensures evaluation. `get` should be self-explaining. For multiple columns you can use `mget`.

Comment: Thanks for the example, please see my edit, I can achieve the same by using mtcars[,myVector[i]]=mydt[,myVector[i],with=FALSE]
mtcars[,myVector]=mydt[,myVector,with=FALSE]. So get is produces the same as using with=FALSE? It's something confusing.

Comment: I believe that approach would not work by reference and thus be inefficient. I haven't checked, though. Generally, you want to avoid `[<-` and `$<-` when using data.table.